# AVAudioPlayer init not working when using Product > Archive, but OK with Sim. and direct-to-device build

Tags: swift, xcode6.1

In Xcode 6.1, using Swift, I am trying to instantiate an AVAudioPlayer. A class var defines it:

```
var musicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
```

Then in init I setup the musicPlayer:

```
let musicSoundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("music", withExtension: "wav")
musicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: musicSoundURL, error: nil)
```

This runs in Simulator. This runs via direct build to an iPhone 6.

So I want to create the product archive for distribution on Apple TestFlight. I use Product > Archive. When I do this, this code refuses to compile:

```
musicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: musicSoundURL, error: nil)
```

With an error of "Extra argument 'contentsOfURL' in call.

I just cannot understand why Product > Archive would take exception with this line. I have deleted the parameters and allows XCode to template out the usage, and it produces the precise code above (that I remind you works in Sim and direct-to-iPhone build).

I'm stumped!

Comment: OK this issue has gone away having just updated to 6.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgrade to XCode 6.1.1 to resolve this issue.